# How to create a PDF document with header from a template with docx4j?

Tags: docx4j

I want to create a document from an existing Word 2010 document and convert it to PDF using docx4j 3.1.0. I've built upon the sample in

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java

The Word document already contains a header with text and an image that I do not modify in my processing. The resulting PDF document, however, doesn't contain the header.

Is this someting that is supposed to work? If yes: how can I find out what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you can see the header when you "save as PDF" in Word, then you should also see the header in docx4j's PDF output.

To have it fixed, we'll need to see the docx.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer encouraged me to take the effort of removing all the content processing in my code, so that the original, unmodified document was saved (or at least: should be). It turned out that it contained the header then. I also could identify the piece of code that caused the header to disapper. I will need to check this with the colleague who wrote it. I will probably come back with a more specific question after that.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the curious reader: the specific cause for the missing header turned out to be a wrong approach of setting page margins on the document. Instead of modifiying the existing settings via `body.getSectPr().getPgMar()` (or even simpler: setting it in the template right away), the code created new `PageDimensions` and set a new `SectPtr` on the body, thereby somehow overwriting or removing the header.